# Geocode Javascript problem

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

Because of loading issues, I've moved the map options code to my HTML form, rather than it being in a separate Javascript file.

The problem is that I now can't get the Geocode functionality to work. I've added my code below. I'm sure it must be something simple, but I'm a little perplexed by this. I just wondered whether it would be at all possible please that someone could let me know where I've gone wrong.

Many thanks

```
function geocode() {

    // This is defining the global variables
    var geocoder, marker;

    // This is making the link with the 'Search For Location' HTML form
    var form = document.getElementById('searchforlocationform');

    // This is catching the forms submit event
    form.onsubmit = function() {

    // This is getting the Address from the HTML forms 'Address' text box
    var address = document.getElementById('inputaddress').value;

    // This is making the Geocoder call
    getCoordinates(address);

    // This is preventing the form from doing a page submit
    return false;
    }
    }
    function geocodePosition(pos) {
    geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
    }, 

    function(responses) {
        if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
    updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
    updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
    });
    }

    //New Code
    function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
    document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
    }

    //Changed 'address' to 'returnedaddress'
    function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
    document.getElementById('returnedaddress').value= str;
    }

    // This creates the function that will return the coordinates for the address
    function getCoordinates(address) {

    // This checks to see if there is already a geocoded object. If not, it creates one
    if(!geocoder){geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();}

    // This is creating a GeocoderRequest object
    var geocoderRequest = {address: address}

    // This is making the Geocode request
    geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest, function(results, status) {

     // Check if status is OK before proceeding
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

    // Center the map on the returned location
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

    // Check to see if we've already got a Marker object
    if (!marker) {
    map.setZoom(16); 
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map, draggable:true
    });
    }

    // Setting the position of the marker to the returned location
    marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);

    // Add dragging event listeners.
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, function() {
    updateMarkerAddress;
    });

    //This fills out the 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' text boxes on the HTML form
    document.getElementById('osgb36lat').value= results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById('osgb36lon').value= results[0].geometry.location.lng();

    //This allows the marker to be draggable and tells the 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' text boxes on the HTML form to update with the new co-ordinates as the marker is dragged
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',     
    function() {    
    updateMarkerStatus;
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
    document.getElementById('osgb36lat').value = marker.position.lat();         
    document.getElementById('osgb36lon').value = marker.position.lng();

    });

    // Update current position info.
    latLng = [marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng()].join(', ');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());



    var point = marker.getPosition();
    map.panTo(point);   
    }  
    } 
)
    }


<script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            window.onload = function(){
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007);
                var options = {
                zoom: 6,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
                },
                navigationControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
                },
                scaleControl: true,
                scaleControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
        } 
                }; 
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
            }
        })();

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seen to be trying to call updateMarkerAddress with `updateMarkerAddress;` and updateMarkerStatus with `updateMarkerStatus;`, here you are missing `(/*some param*/)`.
What are the loading issues? Maybe if you show your html someone could help with that too.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to read my reply. I've added the section of HTML that deals with the map. I'm not sure whether this is enough? It's just that my HTML form is quite a size in it's entirity. When the map options were contained in the Javascript code, the map took a while to render, whereas within the HTMl it loads considerably quicker. I also trying to mitigate a problem I had with trying to run my geocode and reverse geocode Javascript files together i.e. they don't work. I did send a post earlier on in the week about this, but sadly didn't receive a reply.